# What is the correct way of triggering a function upon saving a settings page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, save, settings

I'm making a simple plugin that generates some CSS based on some settings within an admin page. I would like the function that does the CSS generation to run when this settings page is saved.

What is the correct way of handling this?

I have tried using "update_option_{option}", but this only triggers when the specified setting has been updated, not when it is saved. i.e. if the setting hasn't changed, it doesn't trigger the CSS generation function.

I have tried using "pre_update_option_{option}", which does trigger the function (I think), but doesn't save the setting.

I've also tested the function on "admin_init", and it works, but this is obviously not a viable solution.

**Registering the settings**

```
function geo_accessibility_admin_settings_function(){
    add_settings_section('geo-accessibility-settings', '', 'geo_accessibility_admin_settings_intro_text', 'geo_accessibility_settings');
    
    register_setting('geo-accessibility-settings', 'geo_accessibility_mode_active');
    add_settings_field('geo-accessibility-mode-active', 'Active', 'geo_accessibility_mode_active', 'geo_accessibility_settings', 'geo-accessibility-settings');
    
    register_setting('geo-accessibility-settings', 'geo_accessibility_tab_position');
    add_settings_field('geo-accessibility-tab-position', 'Tab Position', 'geo_accessibility_tab_position', 'geo_accessibility_settings', 'geo-accessibility-settings');
    
    register_setting('geo-accessibility-settings', 'geo_accessibility_tab_size');
    add_settings_field('geo-accessibility-tab-size', 'Tab Size', 'geo_accessibility_tab_size', 'geo_accessibility_settings', 'geo-accessibility-settings');
    
    register_setting('geo-accessibility-settings', 'geo_accessibility_tab_hide');
    add_settings_field('geo-accessibility-tab-hide', 'Tab Hidden', 'geo_accessibility_tab_hide', 'geo_accessibility_settings', 'geo-accessibility-settings');
    
    register_setting('geo-accessibility-settings', 'geo_accessibility_tab_colour');
    add_settings_field('geo-accessibility-tab-colour', 'Tab Colour', 'geo_accessibility_tab_colour', 'geo_accessibility_settings', 'geo-accessibility-settings');
    
    register_setting('geo-accessibility-settings', 'geo_accessibility_icon_colour');
    add_settings_field('geo-accessibility-icon-colour', 'Icon Colour', 'geo_accessibility_icon_colour', 'geo_accessibility_settings', 'geo-accessibility-settings');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'geo_accessibility_admin_settings_function');
```

**Calling the function**

```
function generate_options_css(){
    
    // do stuff
}
add_action('update_option_geo_accessibility_mode_active', 'generate_options_css', 10, 2);
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/ 

Comment: @mikerojas The settings aren't in a post type, though.